# Adding to string in PHP not working

Tags: php

I'm making a bot that returns Mojang's server status. Here's the code.

```
$scan = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://status.mojang.com/check"), true);

$errors = array();

if ($scan[0]["minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Minecraft is down: ");
}

if ($scan[1]["session.minecraft.net"] !== "green" || $scan[6]["sessionserver.minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "All server sessions are down. ");
}

if ($scan[2]["account.minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Account services are down. ");
}

if ($scan[3]["auth.minecraft.net"] !== "green" || $scan[5]["authserver.minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Authentication servers are down. ");
}

if ($scan[4]["skins.minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Skin servers are down. ");
}

$message = "Sometimes it's Mojang... ";

if (sizeof($errors) !== 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $i) {
        $message .= $errors[$i];
    }
} else {
    $message .= "but today, it seems like all of Mojang's servers are working fine!";
}

echo $message;
```

Whenever I execute this in my terminal, it outputs "Sometimes it's Mojang... ", and that's it. There's nothing else. Either way, if the `if` is true or false, it will add something to the string, so it should be printing more than that, but it isn't. Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if this is an easy fix.

Thank you!

Comment: Change this foreach ($errors as $i) { to foreach ($errors as $i => $val) { reason u use value as index thats why its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Two ways

You are passing the value as keys then the value is not found

use key instead of val

```
 foreach ($errors as $i => $val) {
    $message .= $errors[$i];
 }
```

Or use direct value

```
 foreach ($errors as $i) {
    $message .= $i;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem! :)

Comment: @Mistri if its help give us positive feedback have a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your if statement, you are trying to access variables to do not exist. For example, `account.minecraft.net` should be `account.mojang.com`. PHP should have outputted errors, but they must be suppressed on your setup. Here is a fixed file, using the correct keys:

```
$scan = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://status.mojang.com/check"), true);
$errors = array();

if ($scan[0]["minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Minecraft is down: ");
}

if ($scan[1]["session.minecraft.net"] !== "green" || $scan[6]["sessionserver.mojang.com"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "All server sessions are down. ");
}

if ($scan[2]["account.mojang.com"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Account services are down. ");
}

if ($scan[3]["auth.mojang.com"] !== "green" || $scan[5]["authserver.mojang.com"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Authentication servers are down. ");
}

if ($scan[4]["skins.minecraft.net"] !== "green") {
    array_push($errors, "Skin servers are down. ");
}

$message = "Sometimes it's Mojang... ";

if (sizeof($errors) !== 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $i) {
        $message .= $errors[$i];
    }
} else {
    $message .= "but today, it seems like all of Mojang's servers are working fine!";
}

echo $message;
```

Running the updated file on my local server yields the following result: `Sometimes it's Mojang... but today, it seems like all of Mojang's servers are working fine!`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This was a problem, but I couldn't have solved it until Maninderpreet helped with the `for` loop. Thanks anyways!